# How to Pass DOM element to Aurelia function?

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to pass the DOM element to Aurelia function, but it ain't work.
Just to notice that this element is not in the 'repeat.for' statement.

I have something like this, which obviously is not correct :

```
<span click.trigger="passDom(d)">Pass Dom Element</span>


export class Test {

  passDom(d) {
    console.log(d);
  }
}
```

I try using $self, but not working as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `$event.target` like this:

```
<span click.trigger="passDom($event.target)">Pass Dom Element</span>
```

You can read more about DOM events in [Aurelia Hub - DOM Events](https://aurelia.io/docs/binding/basics#dom-events).

> Use the special $event property to access the DOM event in your binding expression.

Alternatively, you can create reference to DOM event and use it from view model:

```
<span click.trigger="passDom()" ref="myElement">Pass Dom Element</span>

// in view model
export class Test {
  passDom() {
    console.log(this.myElement);
  }
}
```

Also available in [Aurelia Hub - Referencing Elements](https://aurelia.io/docs/binding/basics#referencing-elements).

> Use the `ref` binding command to create a reference to a DOM element. The `ref` command's most basic syntax is `ref="expression"`. When the view is data-bound the specified expression will be assigned the DOM element.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you could do if `this.myElement` is too much magic within the VM, is to pass the reference to the function directly:

```
<span click.trigger="passDom(myElement)" ref="myElement">Pass Dom Element</span>

// in view model
export class Test {
  passDom(passedElement) {
    console.log(passedElement);
  }
}
```